# Input.GetKeyUp Как настроить в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Знаю как писать код но не знаю как использовать в Unity хочу что бы при нажатии открывалось окно (Canvas)
Код

```
public class ESC : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp("space"))
        {
            print("Space key was released");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить ссылку на Canvas в эдиторе

```
public class ESC : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _canvas;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp("space"))
        {
            _canvas.SetActive(!_canvas.activeSelf);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо писал такое на других форумах не помогли нормаль но здесь лучше всех спасибо вам

Comment: Можете подсказать как сделать одностороннее открытие

Comment: В скобках метода SetActive укажите True вместо !_canvas.activeSelf

Comment: Спасибо очень помогли